# find how many array values have an absolute value

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend

**i want to find number of failed values in an array**

```
let courcesStatus = ["passed", "failed", "passed", "passed", "passed", "failed"];
```

**for example want to have 2 here as the number of failed values in this array**

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. But first ***>>>[Do some research, search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+count+elements+in+array+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, using `filter()` and `length`:

```js
let courcesStatus = ["passed", "failed", "passed", "passed", "passed", "failed"];

const howManyFailed = arr => arr.filter(value => value === "failed").length;
console.log(howManyFailed(courcesStatus)); // 2
```

You could also achieve this with `reduce()`:

```js
let courcesStatus = ["passed", "failed", "passed", "passed", "passed", "failed"];

const howManyFailed = arr => arr.reduce((accu, curr) => accu + (curr === "failed" ? 1 : 0), 0)
console.log(howManyFailed(courcesStatus)); // 2
```

More information on both of those methods here:

- `.filter()` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))
- `.reduce()` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))